# Unexpected token I JSON

Tags: javascript, json, token

I am trying to use ajax on a registration page in order to show either succes or errors. I cannot figure out why i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I " in the console. Here is the code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var username= $('#userName').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var country = $('#country option:selected').text();
    var password1 = $('#password1').val();
    var password2 = $('#password2').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax-api.php",
      type:'post', data:{name:name, surname:surname, username:username, email:email, country:country, password1:password1, password2:password2, submit:'yes'}
    }).done(function(response) {
      var errors = JSON.parse(response);
      if(errors != ''){
        var outputString = '';
        for(var key in errors){
            outputString += errors[key]+'<br /><br />';
        }
        alertify.error(outputString);
      }else{
        alertify.succes('You have been registered!');
      }
    });

    });
});
```

The console says the error is in line 20 (`var errors = JSON.parse(response);`)

EDIT:  I only get the console error in the success case( `alertify.succes('You have been registered!');`)

Comment: Seems like it is already an object you dont need to parse it again using `var errors = JSON.parse(response);` jquery parses it for you automatically based on the contenttype in the response header.

Comment: Did you examine the value of `response`?

Comment: set the ajax `dataType: 'json'` and you jQuery will handle the `JSON.parse`

Comment: Now i seem to get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Check if you JSON is valid: http://jsonlint.com/